# Tensorflow implementation of the Thomson model

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow

I've implemented the [Thomson model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomson_problem) in Tensorflow and it seems to work very well. I'm repeating some computation by computing the other half of the symmetric distance matrix. I think, for a GPU based approach (though I may be wrong), the savings from a vectorized computation is worth the doubling of my model size. Any comments or suggestions are welcome.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def thompson_model(N):

    # Start with random coordinates from a normal dist
    r0 = np.random.normal(size=[N, 3])
    coord = tf.Variable(r0, name='coordinates')

    # Normalize the coordinates onto the unit sphere
    coord = coord/tf.reshape(tf.norm(coord, axis=1), (-1, 1))

    def squared_diff(A):
        r = tf.reduce_sum(A*A, 1)
        r = tf.reshape(r, [-1, 1])
        return r - 2*tf.matmul(A, tf.transpose(A)) + tf.transpose(r)

    RR = squared_diff(coord)

    # We don't need to compute the gradient over the symmetric distance
    # matrix, only the upper right half
    mask = np.triu(np.ones((N, N), dtype=np.bool_), 1)

    R = tf.sqrt(tf.boolean_mask(RR, mask))

    # Electostatic potential up to a constant, 1/r
    U = tf.reduce_sum(1/R)

    return U, coord
```